# Trying to test if proxy is working

Tags: shell-script, proxy

I wrote this simple script:

```
export http_proxy='http://proxy.test.cz:1234/'
wget -nvq --proxy-user=test --proxy-password=test google.com &>/dev/null | grep -q 'You cant user internet' || echo "Proxy isnt working. " | mail -s "Proxy isnt working" -r "No-reply<no-reply@soma.cz>" test@mail.cz
```

Steps taken:

1. Export the address of our proxy.
2. Download from `www.google.com` with `wget`.
3. Check result from proxy for 'You cant user internet'
4. If found, then it should end but where not found it should send email to my address.

Problem is that it sends email even if it finds 'You cant user internet'.

Answer (score 1):

use ( ) in your echo block

```
wget -nvq --proxy-user=test --proxy-password=test google.com &>/dev/null | grep -q 'You cant user internet' || (echo "Proxy isnt working. " | mail -s "Proxy isnt working" -r "No-reply<no-reply@soma.cz>" test@mail.cz)
```

try this script.. in your onliner, you are running the wget in background and trying to grep the contents...

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT_FILE=/tmp/$$.txt
wget -nvq --proxy-user=test --proxy-password=test google.com > ${OUTPUT_FILE} 2>&1

grep -q 'You cant user internet' ${OUTPUT_FILE}
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
then
    echo "Proxy isnt working. " | mail -s "Proxy isnt working" -r "No-reply<no-reply@soma.cz>" test@mail.cz
else
    echo "Proxy is working"
fi
```